# Apply a function to one column only, with a variable location

Tags: awk

I have a bunch of different files.  All files contain a column titled ID, but not necessarily in the same location in all of the files.  I have a function I want to apply to ID in all of the files to change them into NEWID.

I know that if I pass in the column number of ID I can do this pretty simply, say it's the 3rd column in a 5 column file with something like:

```
awk -v column=$COLNUMBER '{print $1, $2, FUNCTION($column), $4, $5}' FILE
```

However if all of my files have hundreds of columns and it's somewhere arbitrary in each file, this is incredibly tedious.  I am looking for a way to do something along the lines of this:

```
awk -v column=$COLNUMBER '{print #All columns before $column, FUNCTION($column), #All columns after $column}' FILE
```

I've tried different loops but haven't gotten any to work yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple:

```
$ awk -v column=$COLNUMBER '{ $column = FUNCTION($column); print }' $FILE
```

Comment: Just be aware it will compress all spaces between fields to a single space and will delete all fields that are empty so fields beyond an empty field will get left-shifted.

Comment: Wow this was perfect.  Awk has so many different options for syntax lol, I get all confused.  To fix the spacing issue just need to start with '{OFS="\t" and then it works like a charm.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Note that if spacing between fields is significant, then your field separator isn't really the default whitespace separator. For this solution to work, and preserve spaces, you must first add a real field separator to the data. Perhaps a comma or some other character that you know will not be present in any valid field. This is pretty easy to do with a separate awk script.

Answer (score 1):

Preserving spacing between fields:

```
$ cat file
a b   c      d e  f
$ gawk -v col=3 '{print gensub("([[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){" col-1 "})[^[:space:]]+","\\1FUNCTION($col)","")}' file
a b   FUNCTION($col)      d e  f
```

or if you're actually looking for the column value to be passed to FUNCTION():

```
$ gawk -v col=3 '{print gensub("([[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){" col-1 "})([^[:space:]]+)","\\1FUNCTION(\\3)","")}' file
a b   FUNCTION(c)      d e  f

$ gawk -v col=4 '{print gensub("([[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){" col-1 "})([^[:space:]]+)","\\1FUNCTION(\\3)","")}' file
a b   c      FUNCTION(d) e  f
```

or:

```
$ gawk -v col=3 '{print gensub("([[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){" col-1 "})[^[:space:]]+","\\1FUNCTION($"col")","")}' file
a b   FUNCTION($3)      d e  f

$ gawk -v col=4 '{print gensub("([[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){" col-1 "})[^[:space:]]+","\\1FUNCTION($"col")","")}' file
a b   c      FUNCTION($4) e  f
```

The above uses GNU awk for gensub(), you can accomplish the same in other awks using multiple sub()s or match()+substr().

From other peoples answers it looks like you might actually want to call FUNCTION() on the value of the field, rather than print FUNCTION(field). If that's the case then you just do:

```
$ gawk -v col=4 '{print gensub("([[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){" col-1 "})[^[:space:]]+","\\1"FUNCTION($col),"")}' file
```

e.g. if FUNCTION was toupper():

```
$ gawk -v col=4 '{print gensub("([[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){" col-1 "})[^[:space:]]+","\\1"toupper($col),"")}' file
a b   c      D e  f
```